# Minimum value of $|z + \frac 12|$?

Tags: complex-numbers

If $z$ is a complex number such that $|z|\ge 2$, then what is the minimum value of $|z+ \frac 12|$?

I first drew a circle(Lets call it Circle 1),centered at origin with radius $2$, Then the arbitrary point $z$ should lie anywhere on or outside the circle.

I figured that $|z + \frac 12|$ resembles the equation of a circle centered at $(-\frac 12,0)$, with variable radius, and that we have to find the minimum value of that radius?

So I considered the real intercepts of Circle 1, and thought that the points $(-2,0)$ and $(2,0)$ should give me the minimum and maximum value of the desired radius.

Oddly enough, one of the options has the solution range of $(\frac 32, \frac 52)$ but it's wrong.

I think the part where I'm going wrong is determining the position of z on Circle 1 so that $|z+ \frac 12|$ is minimised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Triangle's Inequality to get that:

$$\left|z + \frac 12\right| \ge \left||z| - \frac 12\right| = \frac 32$$

Answer (score 0):

Your methodology was correct. $(-2, 0)$ is indeed the $z$ point for which $|z+ \frac 12|$ is minimum.

You still need to calculate $|z+ \frac 12|$ though:

$|z+ \frac 12| = |-2 + \frac 12| = | -\frac 32 | = \frac 32$

Comment: $ \frac 32  $ is indeed the correct answer! I realised that my fault lied not in figuring out the wrong answer but in choosing the correct solution range.